# How to report custom error strings from child process while preserving debugger functionality

Tags: c#, error-handling

I have a program that creates a subprocess and trys to handle any error messages as per below:

```
        study.StartInfo.FileName = studyWorkingDir +"\\"+ clargParts[0];
        study.StartInfo.Arguments = clargs;
        study.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        study.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        study.ErrorDataReceived += (sender,  args) =>
        {
            Process process = (Process)sender;
            if (!process.HasExited)
            {
                MyErrorBroadcaster.BroadcastMessage("Instance error: " + args.Data.ToString());
                process.kill();
            }
        };
        study.Start(); // Start the Study!
        study.PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.BelowNormal;
        study.BeginErrorReadLine();
```

The child process is an application (given below). In order to actually get a non-empty error in the above master process, I've needed to wrap the whole sub-program in a try-catch which makes a custom Console.Error.WriteLine() call

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            Console.Title = "MyProgram";
            Application.Run(new GUI());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine(e.ToString().Replace("\r\n","\t"));
        }

    }
}
```

The problem is, this try-catch in the child program clobbers the debugger from stopping on the actual error locations in visual studio, which I think will annoy/be problematic for me and my coworkers as we develop. (Seems kludgy too!)

Is there a better way to get have this sub-application to report errors to the master process, without affecting normal debugger operation?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you want or not, but you can re-throw the error after writing details out to the console: `throw e;`

Answer (score 0):

Revisiting this, the problem was that the master process was only getting the errors one line at a time and that first line happened to be "", after which it immediately closes the process (ignoring the following error lines). The e.ToString().Replace("\r\n","\t") bypassed this issue by guaranteeing the error was one line, but with unwanted side effects.

A better solution for me was the following:

```
        study.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        study.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        study.Start(); // Start the Study!
        //This thread collects errors until the process ends, then reports them 
        (new Thread(() =>
        {
            //Acumulate errors, then send
            String err = study.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(err))
                MyErrorBroadcaster.BroadcastMessage("Instance Error", "\tInstance error: " + err);
        })).Start();
```

This approach uses the study.StandardError.ReadToEnd(). This command is blocking which would be unsuitable for my purposes, so It is in a lambda thread (so the main program can move on!)